# Toggle button in ApplicationBar in WP7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to have a toogle button in AppBar inside my WP7 app. But I see nothing except ApplicationBarIconButton. 
Is it possible to have a toggle button in AppBar or make ApplicationBarIconButton to act as a toggle button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no toggle button is not possible in the app bar. you can use application bar icon button and change the image depending upon user action